# wordpress: all categories can not be showed in admin page

Tags: wordpress

I am using wordpress, but suddenly, I do not know why I can not list  all categories  even it said I already added some categories, they look like below images:

Category Page:
[image]

Post editing Page:
[image]

is there anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: If you try go to `http://domain.com/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?action=edit&taxonomy=category&tag_ID=1&post_type=post` does anything show?

Comment: it is “Uncategorized”